# delphi firemonkey: how to use image area as a button?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

in my Firemonkey android app, i want to use a area( or an object ) in an image(image is placed in a form) as a button, first i thought about getting touch/click area and process from there, but since device screen could change from device to device, i want to know how to handle this situation ..

just for demonstration see this picture
[image]
<sub>(source: [chainimage.com](https://www.chainimage.com/images/glimpse-of-glamour-%E2%99%A5-if-i-had-it-my-way-everything-would-be.jpg))</sub>

i want to use each item as a button.

how do i do that ? thanks in advance.

Comment: TMS has a hotspotimage for FMX, see: https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxpack.asp?s=fmxmisc

Comment: thanks. I was looking for free solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the `ImageList` in Delphi.

All your images in convert to `Png` or `Ico`. 
Bring all the images in the `ImageList`.

Button connects to the `ImageList`.
In the `ImageIndex` Button to choose your Image.

The greater Button, Image greater.

Using the image in the project, to increase the size of the project.

More information:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.ImgList.TImageList

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer, the spots in that images is in various shapes. anyway I gave up using this idea. thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I explained very simply.

The first one ImageList component in the app. After all it is expanded to upload your photos.

Then ImageIndex photos to assign button.
[image]